# Keybindings with mouse click

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am developing in C#, and when I hold down `cmd` (macOS) and `Click` a method, I am taken to it's `Definition`. I am looking for a way to be able to hold down `cmd`+`shift` and click the method, and be taken to the methods `Implementation`. I have searched and tested for some time without finding anything; I am starting to think it is not possible.

Does anyone know how, or if it even is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's currently impossible. Mouse clicks are not considered modifiers and cannot be customized right now. There's an open issue for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3130.

You can still press **command**+**F12** to jump to **Implementation** (which may be unhandy, since you have to press **Fn** as well). Besides, some applications or specific mouses allow you to map keys.

Comment: Thanks! Now I won't use time on something that is impossible, at least!